# How to recursive sort a python list with many dictionaries and lists inside?

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion

Purpose: Sort a large dictionary(almost 80MB).

Bigger purpose: Used the sorted dictionary to perform a dictdiff from dictdiffer module to find all possible differences, as dictdiffer doesn't sort sub-family dicts,lists,etc just does a row-row comparison which is seeming useless now.

Here is a sample with combinations of sub-dictionaries,lists and strings inside:

A sample sub-family of the large one:

```
{"selector": "bus", "acrh": "isr", "category": ["NONES","BACKEND"], "priority": [4,3,1], "nl_date": "6/19/2005", "rl_date": "", "sl_date": "7/3/2040", "stats": {"ports": 2, "music": "", "jack": [54,34,21]}}
How i want it to be:
{"acrh": "isr","category": ["BACKEND","NONES"],"nl_date": "6/19/2005","priority": [1,3,4],"rl_date": "","selector": "bus", "sl_date": "7/3/2040", "stats": {"jack": [21,34,54],"music": "","ports": 2}}
How logic is printing now:
How i want it to be:
{"acrh": "isr","category": ["BACKEND","NONES"],"nl_date": "6/19/2005","priority":[4,3,1],"rl_date": "","selector": "bus", "sl_date": "7/3/2040", "stats": {"ports": 2, "music": "", "jack": [54,34,21]}}
```

Only keys seem to be sorted,but the sub-list and dicts' values aren't.

My code

````
prj = {"selector": "bus", "acrh": "isr", "category": ["NONES","BACKEND"], "priority": [4,3,1], "nl_date": "6/19/2005", "rl_date": "", "sl_date": "7/3/2040", "stats": {"ports": 2, "music": "", "jack": [54,34,21]}}

spro = {}
        for k,v in sorted(prj.items()):
            spro[k] = boss.gosort(self,v)
            print(k,"->",spro[k])


    def ds(self,d):

        trad = {}
        for key, value in sorted(d.items()):
            if isinstance(value, dict):
                trad[key] = boss.ds(self,value)
            elif isinstance(value, list):
                trad[key] = boss.gosort(self,value)
            else:
                trad[key] = value
        return trad

    def gosort(self,inlist):

        filist = []
        for each in inlist:
            print("each is:",each,type(each))
            if isinstance(each, dict):
                filist.append(boss.ds(self,each))
            elif isinstance(each, list):
                each.sort()
                filist.append(each)
            else:
                filist.append(each)
        return filist  ```

Any help would be appriciated.
````

Comment: Please ignore the line # 5 with "How i want it to be:". Typo

Answer (score 0):

```
x = {"selector": "bus", "acrh": "isr", "category": ["NONES","BACKEND"], "priority": [4,3,1], "nl_date": "6/19/2005", "rl_date": "", "sl_date": "7/3/2040", "stats": {"ports": 2, "music": "", "jack": [54,34,21]}}

def convert(d):
  # sort nested lists
  sort_func = lambda v: v if isinstance(v, str) else sorted(v)
  y = {k:sort_func(v) for k, v in x.items()}

  # using JSON to sort dictionary
  return json.dumps(y, sort_keys=True, indent=2)

print(convert(x))
```

## Output

```
{
  "acrh": "isr",
  "category": [
    "BACKEND",
    "NONES"
  ],
  "nl_date": "6/19/2005",
  "priority": [
    1,
    3,
    4
  ],
  "rl_date": "",
  "selector": "bus",
  "sl_date": "7/3/2040",
  "stats": [
    "jack",
    "music",
    "ports"
  ]
}
```

Comment: TY. In this sort_func = lambda v: v if isinstance(v, list) else sorted(v) i edited the 'str' to 'list' for sort under-lying lists, works with smaller JSONs for now. I will test larger JSONs and will revert.